# OpenSharedItem with Outlook interop throws odd exception with Office 2003, works with Office 2008

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, outlook-2003

I'm using the Office interop API to open a .msg file saved from outlook, and to then show a reply window to allow the user to reply to it.

When running Office 2003, the OpenSharedItem(pathToMSGFile); call throws the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
  protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace.OpenSharedItem(String Path)
  at OutlookTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

When running Office 2008, it works absolutely fine.

I've put together a small test case, the code is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Application app;
        string pathToMSGFile = "\\\\path\\to\\foobar.msg";

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            pathToMSGFile = args[0];
        }

        if (!File.Exists(pathToMSGFile))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist.", pathToMSGFile);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Opening {0}", pathToMSGFile);

        Type olType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application", false);

        app = Activator.CreateInstance(olType) as Application;

        MailItem fld = (MailItem)app.Session.OpenSharedItem(pathToMSGFile);

        _MailItem reply = fld.ReplyAll();
        reply.Save();
        reply.Display(false);

        Console.ReadKey();

        reply.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The application is targeted as .Net 4, using the Office12 interop library. Same happens regardless of whether its compiled for AnyCPU or x86.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note that version 11 of the interop library does not contain an `OpenSharedItem()` method.

It becomes available from version 12 onwards.

It appears that this operation is unavailable on Office 11/2003 (at least not via that method call on any version of the interop lib).

---

I'm not sure if this is suitable for your scenario, but I've had good success with the Outlook Redemption library.

From [What is Outlook Redemption?](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm):

> Outlook Redemption works around limitations imposed by the Outlook Security Patch plus provides a number of objects and functions to work with properties and functionality not exposed through the Outlook object model.
>
> Redemption library also includes the RDO (Redemption Data Objects) family of objects that can function as a complete CDO 1.21 or Outlook Object Model replacement.

It seems to circumvent some of these odd/inconsistent behaviours b/w different versions of Outlook (either by design or as a "side effect" of the original goal).

If you're otherwise familiar with CDO, you'll be comfortable with RDO.  But to be honest I don't know how it "maps" to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.

Refer http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/rdosession.htm

The equivalent RDO function for `Session.OpenSharedItem()` is `RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile()`.

NB I'm in no way affiliated with this product, other than I've used it on occasion! :-)

Comment: Interesting, but I can't really bring in extra libraries to a LOB application without a great deal of pain. Especially a closed source one that can't be reviewed first.

Comment: @PhonicUK I note that the v11 interop library does not contain an `OpenSharedItem()` method.  It becomes available from the Office 12 version onwards.  Is this operation simply unavailable (via the interop) on Office 11/2003?

Comment: that would indeed seem to be the issue. If you'd like to post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @PhonicUK Have updated this answer to state same, left comments in about RDO in case others in future can use this in their scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you try to save a message that contains a large number of attachments. When you find a message in Outlook, the menu file -> saveas also end up with the same error.

Comment: please try to improve your answer by adding relevant code .. put some effort in the answer so ppl can understand you better .. welcome to stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading E-mails From Outlook 2003 office is Possible But Not from the Path ( to .msg file)
but we can read the E-mails Messages within the Outlook Folder( default / Other Folders ) as Mail-Items object.

If its coded in COM object 12.0 outlook object library and used in office 2003 (which has outlook 11.0 object lib) obviously it won't work !

`The Error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`  will mainly occurs if **.dll** files are missing so its better to put related **.dll** files or install upgraded office 2007,2010. this solves it.

We can Read E-mail Messages From Higher version of office like office 2007,2010 etc with the method  as shown below.

```
outlook._Application X=new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MAPIFolder=;  //...... Default Folderof outlook
String Path="......\...\temp.msg";
Outlook._MailItem Mail=(Outlook.MailItem)(X.Session.OpenSharedItem(Path);
```

you can Access Mail and Program it.